# open and edit a .PLM file PowerLoom

Tags: command

Yesterday I made some stuff in a new .PLM PowerLoom file. I saved it, and today I would like to know how to open it and edit it to add others things, but how ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found. You have to do that :

```
(in-package "STELLA")
(load "NAME_OF_YOUR_PLM_FILE")
(in-module "NAME_OF_THE_MODULE")
```

and then you are in your file